# How to create a .NET/MVC gridview with drag-and-drop images that swap with each other?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, drag-and-drop, grid

I'm tasked with creating a website application that resembles a POS (Point-of-Sale) system's editing suite, which shows a grid of images with a fixed number of rows/columns (8X4 for 40 total squares) that show (food) menu items.  For example, row/column 1/1 might show an icon for "Combo Meal #1" and row/column 1/2 might show "Combo Meal #2" etc.  The POS system allows users to drag one of the icons from a grid location onto another, and then the two of them swap.  I.e., if you dragged the icon for Combo Meal #1 onto Combo Meal #2, then they would trade places in the gridview.

Nothing on Stack seems to fit this exact case, as I'd like to use .NET MVC if possible; I also cannot find anything in the Telerik tools that are a ready-fit solution.  These two links are the closest that I've seen:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-refreshPositions

http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/

...but they are only partial solutions.

Does anyone know of a tool that actually provides for this behavior?  Or have any insight into how I can do this myself?  (I'm still going through the learning curve on MVC, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Telerik, but as you posted jQuery, does this [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid) example not work?

Comment: Doh!  I thought I'd looked at all the examples on that site, but must have missed the bottom one.  I will try to see if that can work for me (it looks like it would) and hopefully be able to report some success.  Thanks for the sharp eyes, MalSu.

Comment: No problem. You'll find all the documentation and examples there as well. 
Look into [jQuery Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) and [jQuery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) for further insight.
Good luck!